# Customizing JSON.Net output

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

Back story: I started to use the JSON serializer build into .net but quickly ran into a fair few limitation.

With the way that I need to publish data, its more for producing summaries of object graphs rather than full data dumps. I never know how big these graphs are going to be, where they will cause exceptions, etc.

Based on what I need to do the following are my requirements (note some of these I can do, others I can't find a point of reference within JSON.Net as to where I would build the functionality):

- Handel exceptions as trying to seralize graph - CAN DO

  - The property that caused the exception should still be included in the JSON output and the value be the exception type - ????
- Handel circular references - CAN DO
- Trimming massive strings - CAN DO
- Object graph deepth trimming - ????
- Object graph sibling count trimming - ????
- Object graph total node count trimming - ????
- Serializing different objects in the graph differently to other objects (i.e. have a different JsonSerializerSettings for different properties) - ????

If anyone can give me any pointers as to which direction to go to be able to target the various points that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking out the Linq-to-Json in Json.NET for most of these?  (even though it would probably get ugly)

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx